# Using vue js without components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I went through laracasts vuejs tutorials few times, thenetninja on youtube and few others..

So I decided to change my website front into vue because of reactivity.
Like for toggles and other stuff. But there are also components which are very useful and cool but in my case it seems like they are mostly unneeded.

Every tutorial is about basic things but in my case where I have:

```
<component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
</component-a>
<component-c></component-c>
```

And inside `<component-b>` I click on button and with that I need to change something in `<component-c>`.

I don't know how to do this besides adding everything inside one component which is not the case because some things are not supposed to be rendered if user is not logged in:

```
<component-c>
    @if(auth()->user())
    <component-d></component-d>
    @endif
    <component-e></component-e>
</component-c>
```

And I can't use php inside .vue :D

So I leave everything as it is and make reactivity based on that without using components.

Is that bad?

If it is, how to alter component-d on some click inside component-b with using components?

(In my case, B is dropdown menu from topbar and D is tab section that changes on that dropdown menu item clicks)

Answer (score 0):

If certain content must be hidden from the client you can't use vue and just keep using php and laravel blade's `@if`, but then "reactivity" can only take place on a full page load.

If the content must only be hidden visually, of can be retrieved via an API then you can use Vue directives like `v-if`, `v-show` and use javascript to show and hide components.

Comment: Why **If certain content must be hidden from the client you can't use vue and just keep using php and laravel** ?

Comment: Because the content is sent to to client, so when you press view-source it's readable. That not what you want if the content should only be available for paid users.

Comment: I didnt even look in that, was looking by inspecting elements. What should I do in case I already did everything in laravel and it took me over 30h to change 1/5 front in vue components :D I am already so pissed and since you are here. Is it bad to still use jquery when these days there are so many front js frameworks?

Comment: My advise go for developer-happyness. For me that's Vue, for others it's jQuery. But component based frontends like Vue do provide nice things. try it again for a new smaller project.

Comment: Whats better for user experience and user interface? :D If you use vue, how do you use it with php? :D

Comment: I'd use vue as a SPA, with vue-router etc. I'd only use php for the json api when i need to load additional/dynamic data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181445/discussion-between-learner-and-bob-fanger).

Comment: so basically i should use api for everything even something like i would do in blade like: auth()->user()->age or something